# Does Android In-App Subscription purchaseTime inside PurchaseData class Update With Each Monthly Renewal?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hii i m using this https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 library. i have implemented subscriptions using this but i m not sure when the subscription renew after first month does the purchaseTime inside PurchaseData is updated in subsequent months afterwards or purchaseTime contains the first time i have purchased subscription ? plz help. thanks in advance. i have viewed similar questions but could not find any answer.

Comment: why use a third party library for this ? couldn't you just use what google provides directly ?

Comment: i have used google code also. it does not provide me renewal date either or expiry date.

Comment: if the main api doesn't provide it then i highly doubt a third party library will

Comment: there is alternate api provided by google to check expiry time of subscription but it has some tedious way to implement so that is why i used library which checks in background.